# NSAttributedString doesn't show part of the text

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

I need to create an attributed string:

```
NSString *forecastLow = [forecast valueForKey: @"low"];
NSString *forecastHigh = [forecast valueForKey: @"high"];
self.forecastLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName: @"PT Sans" size: 13];
NSMutableAttributedString *attriburedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/%@\u00B0", forecastLow, forecastHigh]];
[attriburedString addAttribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                         value: [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.f green: 0.f blue: 0.f alpha: 1.f]
                             range: NSMakeRange(0, [forecastLow length])];
 attriburedString addAttribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                             value: [UIColor colorWithRed: 10 green: 10 blue: 10 alpha: 1]
                             range: NSMakeRange([forecastLow length], [attriburedString length] - 1)];
 self.forecastLabel.attributedText = attriburedString;
```

but the second part of it isn't displayed on the screen, just white color.
when I'm making log of the attributed sting, it shows the full string.
what's the problem?

Comment: Check the size of your label or textview to make sure it has enough space for the entire string

Comment: @JackWu, when I am showing the text without attributes it works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating the 2nd color incorrectly. This:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed: 10 green: 10 blue: 10 alpha: 1]
```

should be:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed: 10/255.0 green: 10/255.0 blue: 10/255.0 alpha: 1]
```

The values need to be in the range 0.0 - 1.0. Anything over 1.0 gets treated as 1.0 therefore your code specified a white color (all 1.0).